# How to make this Flask-mysql insert commit?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

I'm still using Flask-mysql.

I'm getting the database context (the mysql variable) just fine, and can query on the database / get results.  It's only the insert that is not working: it's not complaining (throwing Exceptions).  It returns `True` from the insert method.

This should be done inserting the record when it commits, but for some reason, as I watch the MySQL database with `MySQL Workbench`, nothing is getting inserted into the table (and it's not throwing exceptions from the insert method):

I'm passing in this to `insertCmd`:

```
"INSERT into user(username, password) VALUES ('test1','somepassword');"
```

I've checked the length of the column in the database, and copied the command into `MySQL Workbench` (where it successfully inserts the row into the table).

I'm at a loss.  The examples I've seen all seem to follow this format, and I have a good database context.  You can see other things I've tried in the comments.

```
def insert(mysql, insertCmd):
     try:
        #connection = mysql.get_db()
        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
        cursor.execute(insertCmd)
        mysql.connect().commit()
        #mysql.connect().commit
        #connection.commit()
        return True
     except Exception as e:
        print("Problem inserting into db: " + str(e))
        return False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to keep a handle to the connection; you keep overriding it in your loop.

Here is a simplified example:

```
con = mysql.connect()
cursor = con.cursor()

def insert(mysql, insertCmd):
     try:
        cursor.execute(insertCmd)
        con.commit()
        return True
     except Exception as e:
        print("Problem inserting into db: " + str(e))
        return False
```

If `mysql` is your connection, then you can just commit on that, directly:

```
def insert(mysql, insertCmd):
  try:
    cursor = mysql.cursor()
    cursor.execute(insertCmd)
    mysql.commit()
    return True
  except Exception as e:
    print("Problem inserting into db: " + str(e))
    return False
  return False
```

Comment: Thanks!  Trying that now.  Also, Laurent, thanks for pointing that out.  Deleting the last return.

Comment: Works!  Thanks a lot!  No idea why my attempts in the comments didn't stumble into that, could've sworn I was committing on the connection.  I'll have to examine it carefully now.

Comment: A classic usage is also to rollback the last sql execution on exception…

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you MUST separate the connect and cursor, or it won't work.

To get the cursor, this will work:  cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()

However, as Burchan Khalid so adeptly pointed out, any attempt after that to make a connection object in order to commit will wipe out the work you did using the cursor.

So, you have to do the following (no shortcuts):

```
connection = mysql.connect()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(insertCmd)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: I'm leaving Khalid's up as the answer and putting this up to help solidify it.

Comment: Here's the full repo with all the flask code involved:
https://github.com/DiginessForever/flicklistBlog.git

I've been doing all kinds of regex matches, etc.  These latest changes will be committed soon (with a bunch of other minor fixes from the last few hours).